# How to pre-load a 3D model from file and use it multiple times in OSG?

Tags: c++, 3d, openscenegraph

Is it there a way to pre-load a static 3D model file using `osgDB` and then use the same model multiple times in a scene without having to neither copy the `osg::Node` nor load the file once again?

The ideal situation would be if the model data could be stored in a class pointed to by a  `osg::ref_ptr` which would be then redistributed between the nodes representing the object in the scene.

Comment: 'osg::Node' inherits from osg::Referenced, so it is reference counted. Just load it once at the beginning of your program, store it as an osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> somewhere and use it whenever/wherever you like (under other transform nodes); there will be no duplication of the model as you'll always use the same instance, and you wont need to load it again.

Comment: osgDB::Registry supports caching of loaded model files -- and various levels, geometries, textures, etc.... Just pass in the Registry flags to osgDB::readNodeFile (or the other osgDB loader functions). One of the "newer" features of this method (this was introduced somewhere in the osg 2.x era) is the ability to write your own reader callback, so that you can customize the standard calls with your own system if you don't want to use the default Registry implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just put osg::Group's or instances of some subclass of it where you want the node to be in your scene, and call addChild(node) to the groups.

Usually, the Group subclass I'd use would be an osg::PositionAttitudeTransform or an osg::MatrixTransform, so that I can apply a transform to them too.

-hope that helps-

Answer (score 0):

Using osg::Node you can use clone method and define which data are copied between object during cloning.
Look at example code:

```
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group> root = new osg::Group;
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> n = osgDB::readNodeFile(fn);
// n2 will be deep copy of n - all data of n will be copied to n2
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> n2 = dynamic_cast<osg::Node*>(n->clone(osg::CopyOp::DEEP_COPY_ALL));
// n3 will be shallow copy of n - all possible data will be shared between n3 and n
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> n3 = dynamic_cast<osg::Node*>(n->clone(osg::CopyOp::SHALLOW_COPY));
```

Using clone method and copyOp enum you can easily define which data is shared and which is copied. More can be found here [OSG Documentation](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/documentation/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs/a00175.html#ac6d7266aba298bf11e821248db07d262).

I haven't found any preloading options for osgDB, but it can be easily implemented like that:

```
class GraphFilesManager {
    static osg::Node* GraphFilesManager::readNodeFile(std::string file)
    {
        bool wasLoaded = false;
        for (int i=0; i < loadedNodefilenames.size(); i++)
        {
        if (file.compare (loadedNodefilenames[i])==0)
            {
                osg::Node* newNode = dynamic_cast<osg::Node*>( loadedNode[i]->clone(osg::CopyOp::DEEP_COPY_NODES));
                return newNode;
            }
        }
        osg::Node* newNode = osgDB::readNodeFile(file);
        if (newNode)
        {
            loadedNode.push_back(newNode);
            loadedNodefilenames.push_back(file);
        }
        return newNode;
    }
    static std::vector <osg::Node*> loadedNode;
    static std::vector <std::string> loadedNodefilenames;
}
```

In my application number of models is very low, and I had to make deep copy.
Hope it helped.

Comment: And what would be the difference between 'cloning' and 'copying'? The op asks for a way of not having to copy the node. Your loader seems to do the appropriate job, however.